# Update values on multiple rows where a condition is fulfilled - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to change the last character to 0 in `zip_code` column of the rows that are in this selection :
`SELECT * FROM city WHERE MOD(CAST(zip_code AS int), 10) <> 0;`

```
  zip_code | city
+----------+-------------------
| 75001    | Paris
| 97416    | Saint-Leu
| 20137    | Porto-Vecchio
| 97115    | Sainte-Rose
| 69001    | Lyon
| 97139    | Abymes
| 97139    | Les Abymes
| 97437    | Saint-Benoît
| 97233    | Schoelcher
| 97419    | La Possession
...
```

So I should obtain :

```
  zip_code | city
+----------+-------------------
| 75000    | Paris
| 97410    | Saint-Leu
| 20130    | Porto-Vecchio
| 97110    | Sainte-Rose
| 69000    | Lyon
| 97130    | Abymes
| 97130    | Les Abymes
| 97430    | Saint-Benoît
| 97230    | Schoelcher
| 97410    | La Possession
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE foo
SET zip_code = CONCAT(LEFT(zip_code, LENGTH(zip_code)-1), '0')
WHERE RIGHT(zip_code, 1) <> '0';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7e6470419b08d511a3dea5af17150df8)

Answer (score 2):

I find that regular expressions are more intuitive:

```
UPDATE foo
    SET zip_code = regexp_replace(zip_code, '.$', '0')
    WHERE zip_code not like '%0';
```

This replaces the last character with `0`.  The `where` clause filters out rows that already have a `'0'` at the end.

Comment: This looks more sophisticated, more intuitive and more readable. Thank you for your help!